# Getting Android Studio, Gradle and Android Annotations working together

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations

now that i've decided to use Android Annotations with Android Studio i wanted to implement it through Gradle. After some thoughtful research i've found out that there are older and newer ways of implementing Android Annotations through Gradle depending on which version android studio, gradle or android annotations have. i came to this useful tutorial -> http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/21/androidannotations-setup-in-android-studio/ , and tried to implement this , at first, with the new 'android-L' as target SDK like

> targetSDKversion "android-L" + compileSdkVersion 20 + buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

until i tried it with

> targetSDKversion 20 + compileSdkVersion 20 + buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

and also

> targetSDKversion 19 + compileSdkVersion 19 + buildToolsVersion "19.1.0".

Everytime i was getting 2 warnings that my java classes dont seem to get precompiled. even though it seems that it pre-creates the build/generated/source/apt directory. but without my pre-processed class from my MainActivity -> MainActivity_

I always do get following Warnings:

> Note: Resolve log file to D:\AndroidProjects\GradleTest\app\build\generated\source\apt\androidannotations.log
>   Note: Initialize AndroidAnnotations 3.0.1 with options >{androidManifestFile=D:\AndroidProjects\GradleTest\app\build\intermediates\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml, resourcePackageName=at.gradle.defuex.gradletest}
>
> warning: Unclosed files for the types '[dummy1407928544078]'; these types will not undergo annotation processing
>
> warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[androidManifestFile, resourcePackageName]'

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript{
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.3'
    }
}


repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "at.gradle.defuex.gradletest"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    signingConfigs{
        releaseConfig{
            storeFile file("gradlekeystore.jks");
            storePassword ("*************");
            keyAlias "keyAlias";
            keyPassword "*************";
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName "at.gradle.defuex.gradletest"
    }
}

dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0+"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0+"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Im using following Versions:

- Android Studio version 0.8.2
- Gradle version 0.12.2
- android-apt version 1.3
- android annotations version 3.0.1 (as seen in the build.gradle file)

> - If there should be a solution to this problem please tell me, because im confused now.
> - If there should be a better annotations framework or a way of using cool annotations, please tell me that too.
> - And if it should not be a common way anymore to use annotations for android projects anyway, please pleeeeease tell me that too.

,but i would prefer a solution to my problem :)

Cheers!

Comment: I would drop AndroidAnnotations in favor to ButterKnife

Comment: i shortly looked over ButterKnife and can see that it seems slightly more understandable. but i could not find any annotations e.g.: @ Background or @ UiThread like in Android Annotations that were always helpful too. Are there any other implementations for functionalities like this or is butterknife mainly for views?

Comment: @ligi Actually ButterKnife only offers a small subset of AA's functionality, but the setup of it requires quite the same effort in build.gradle. :)

Comment: @MadExHatter So what is your question? You do not understand the warnings? Please read [this](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/pull/1084) issue. I do not know what is the problem with the apt arguments, maybe it's a problem with android-apt.

Comment: the problem is that i can't build an .apk version due to the missing MainActivity_ class. furthermore, butterknife is much more easier to implement than AA...just my opinion. because it works like "butter".

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I'm having the same error + error: package javax.annotation.processing does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run **gradlew clean build** from project root. 
Then try to **make** project (button with a green arrow with 0 and 1) before running on a device. Should be fine.

Comment: This doesn't change the situation at all.