# warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[room.schemaLocation]'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I got this warning:

**warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[room.schemaLocation]'**

I've already checked the below links solutions and it seems to be a different problem.
I receive the error while working with Android Studio IDE on an Android project. The error popped up after changes to binding variable in xml (changed type from Integer to int due to Unboxing warning and that i actually only require int).

Already checked below solutions:

[NetBeans bug 233098](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233098)

[getting-android-studio-gradle-and-android-annotations-working-together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290256/getting-android-studio-gradle-and-android-annotations-working-together)

[annotationprocessor-option-not-recorgnized-by-any-processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607509/annotationprocessor-option-not-recorgnized-by-any-processor)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a multi-module project that I added ***room*** to. For my project the problem was caused by adding my `RoomDatabase` derived class to a library module, but configuring the `build.gradle` of my app module.

The solution is to configure the `build.gradle` of the module that contains the `RoomDatabase` derived class.

There are 3 main pieces to the solution:

**1.** Your `RoomDatabase` derived class (`AppDatabase` in this example)

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(SomeWidgetEntity::class), version = 50)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
  //your code goes here
}
```

**2.** In the `build.gradle` file of the module that contains `AppDatabase` add the following to the `defaultConfig{}` section.

```
defaultConfig {

    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
        arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                     "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
        }
    }

}
```

**3.** In the **SAME** `build.gradle` file in the `dependencies{}` section add the dependency for the ***room*** compiler.

```
dependencies {

    //for kotlin based projects (where $room_version is the version of room you're using)
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    //for java based projects
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"

}
```

Comment: Great answer and well explained. This solved my problem and it does have sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I tried deleting the following from the application build.gradle file:

```
 javaCompileOptions {
    annotationProcessorOptions {
        arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                             "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
    }
}
```

Then, I ran "rebuild", added the same segment again and the error disappeared.
I don't know why it solved the problem but it did.

**Note**: Rebuilding\cleaning without removing the above gradle definition didn't work for me so it must be removed and added again before rebuilding.

Comment: This worked to eliminate: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[room.schemaLocation, kapt.kotlin.generated, room.incremental, room.expandProjection]'.  I removed the kapt section from my app build.gradle defaultConfig, and then did a gradle resync, clean, and rebuild.  Then I restored the section and rebuilt again.  The errors were gone.    My settings were:
 kapt {
    arguments {
        arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas".toString())
        arg("room.incremental", "true")
        arg("room.expandProjection", "true")
    }
}

Comment: This does not actually fix the problem. I tried this but no code changes happened so when other people clone the project it will show up for them. Also, if you reclone or restart the project it will show up again...

Answer (score 0):

For maven add the following in the maven compiler plugin configuration:

```
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                         <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The problem was Hilt version was not compatible with the kotlin version.

You can compare the below code in the project-level `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.20"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.46.1"
    }
```

And below code in the module-level `build.gradle` file.

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.46.1"
```

For more information, You can have a look at [Hilt gradle setup.](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup)